# Can not connect Yii2 to mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, yii2

I want to connect my yii2-advance template project to MongoDB but There is a problem.

I have completed the guide [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-mongodb) and I have added these setting to `common/config/main-local.php` and `test-local.php`:

```
<?php
return [
    'components' => [
        'db' => [
            'class' => '\yii\mongodb\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'mongodb://@localhost:27017/medadnoki',
            'options' => [
                "username" => "",
                "password" => ""
            ]
        ],
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
            'useFileTransport' => true,
        ],
    ],
];
```

But when I use this code I got false:

```
use yii\mongodb\Connection;
...
$connection = new Connection();
        if ($connection->getIsActive()) {
            echo "true";
        }
        else {
            echo "false";
        }
```

what is my **code's** problem?

UPDATE1:
 I have tested my code in yii2-basic and I changed the `db.php` to this:

```
return [
    'class' => '\yii\mongodb\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mongodb://root:root@localhost:27017/medadnoki'
];
```

and I added the following code to my controller:

```
if(Yii::$app->db->getIsActive()) {
            echo "true";
        } else {
            echo "false";
        }
```

but it still returns false, Is there any idea solution?
Should I create a connection to db by my hand? Or It handle the connection automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested MongoDB queries in my controller and I got an authentication error.
I set username and password for my database and change `dsn` like this:

`'dsn' => 'mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/medadnoki',`

Then again I got the false error in `getIsActive()` function but my queries work fine. I think the function `Yii::$app->db->getIsActive()` won't check the database connection and is used for other purposes.